# Moving .pyenv folder to another partition, symlinking

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, pyenv

This question is related to programming environment setup for python.

I have run out of space on my home folder on Ubuntu. Python shims are stored in their default location `~/.pyenv` and taking up a lot of space. To create space, I want to move the whole of `.pyenv` folder to another partition.

In my understanding, this should be as simple as cut-pasting the `.pyenv' folder to its desired location and creating a soft link at its original location, pointing to this new location. Something like:

`ln -s ~/drive2/.pyenv ~/.pyenv`

( Where the other disc is mounted at `~/drive2/`  )

However, the solutions I see online are much more 'involved'. [Here's one  example](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/226)

Am I missing something? Only possible issue  I can think of is having too many levels of symlink .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question , this worked well, exactly as expected.
The pyenv root directory (`/home/usename/.pyenv` ) contained a lot of symlinks  but all the relative links pointed to sub-folders inside the .pyenv directory itself. Given this, moving the whole folder to another drive did not cause any problems.
Here's the process I followed-

1. Copy (but not cut) the .pyenv folder recursively to desired location, say `~/drive2/.pyenv`
2. Rename the original .pyenv folder to something else and keep it for the time being, in case something goes wrong
3. Create a `soft` link to replace the original .pyenv folder and point it to your new location. For example: `ln -s ~/drive2/.pyenv ~/.pyenv`
4. Test the system by running some python code that uses virtual environments
5. If all is satisfactory, delete the renamed folder in step 2 to reclaim the space

I am quite sure the same system will work on Windows with the `mkLink` command with the `\D` switch, but someone will have to confirm this.